# Converting objects to arrays

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to paginate csv file and I succeeded with it's data, but I couldn't with the file's header(keys). The error says array_keys expected() to be array but objects given, so I wanna to convert array_keys() to array.

I tried to use toArray() function but useless:

```
public function indexPagination()
    { 
        $products = Product::all();
        $products = $products->toArray();
        $products = Product::paginate(5); 

        return view ('inventory.layout', ['products'=>$products]);
    }
```

The error commes from this section who is gonna shows the file's keys, but error says array_keys() expecting to be array but objects given.... please help

```
<thead>   
    @if ($arrkeys= array_keys($products[0])) 

        @foreach ($arrkeys as $keys)  
            <th>{{$key}}</th>
        @endforeach

    @endif 
    </thead>
```

Comment: The last assignement of the products variable is this: `$products = Product::paginate(5);` and overwrite the line before  `$products = $products->toArray();` so `$products` is an instance of `Paginator` class.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear exactly what your desired result is. It looks like you are trying to paginate over the table headers. If this is correct, the following might suffice:

**Controller**

```
return view ('inventory.layout', [
    'products' => Product::paginate(5),
]);
```

**View**

```
<table>
    <thead>   
        @foreach ($products as $product)  
        <th>{{ $product->name }}</th>
        @endforeach
    </thead>
</table>

{{ $products->links() }}
```

Comment: Thanks man any way I fixed it, it's working great right now. The problem was in view, I converted the variable from object to array who is in array_keys() function who fetching the file's keys. it's this: @if ($arrkeys= array_keys(($products[0])->toArray())).

Comment: Awesome. Would you please write a short answer and mark it as accepted? That way other people see this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

It worked well now through convertin the parameter of array_keys() to array using toArray() function because it was an object before. this is the answer:

```
    @if ($arrkeys= array_keys(($products[0])->toArray()))

        @foreach ($arrkeys as $key)  
            <th>{{$key}}</th>

        @endforeach  
    @endif
```